# Stop node being edited programatically

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have written a module that puts a "generate pdf" link on a node when it is viewed. What I now want to do is lock the original node after the pdf is generated.

I know I could just add a "locked" field to the content type I want to lock, and then programatically set that etc. But I'd prefer it to work with any content type.

How can I programatically disable the editing of a node? I'd prefer to install as few additional modules as possible.

Comment: Did you [try this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48044/disable-editing-of-a-node-after-it-has-been-published)

Answer (score 2):

For this you should have to implement hook_node_grants and hook_node_access_records. It look something like that -

```
 /**
  * Implement @hook_node_grants 
  */
 function MODULENAME_node_grants($account, $op) {

  $grants =array();
  $grants['Node_Edit_Permission'][]=array($account->uid);
 return $grants;
}

/**
 * Implement @hook_node_access_records
 */
function MODULENAME_node_access_records($node) {

  $grants = array();

  if ($node->type == 'node_type') { 
    $user_id = /* list of user id which you want to block */;

     // Revoke Permissions from these Users
    if (!empty($user_id) {
      foreach ($user_id as $uid) {
        if (isset($uid)) {

          $grants[] = array(
            'realm' => 'Node_Edit_Permission',
            'gid' => $uid,
            'grant_view' => 1,
            'grant_update' => 0,
            'grant_delete' => 0,
            'priority' => 0,
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return $grants;
}
```